# If activity is not in backstack - start it, but if it is - relaunch it and remove all activities after it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

*Sorry for my English*

In other words, what want I do.

---

*1)*

`A` **-** `B` **-** `C` **-** `D`

*start* `E`

`A` **-** `B` **-** `C` **-** `D` **-** `E`

---

*2)*

`A` **-** `B` **-** `C` **-** `D`

*start* `B`

`A` **-** `B`

---

How can I do it?

**Update:**

But I also need to able return to previous activity (for instance, from `D` to `C`) by pressing the `Back` button.

*3)*

`A` **-** `B` **-** `C` **-** `D`

press `Back` button

`A` **-** `B` **-** `C`

---

Answer (score 0):

Use finish() in every method where you try to move your activity from one to another. Eg.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(a.this, b.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

So when you come back to activity b it will automatically finish all other activity. Use this `finish()` in every Intent where you are trying to move from one activity to other.

Comment: see my updated question. I suppose that in this way I cannot return from `D` to `C` by pressing `Back` button, don't you?

Comment: I am not getting you, can you tell me what exactly you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

You can use `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` from B.
Documentation [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

Comment: [HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/wcfo8k82662uw3v/tuto.zip) is the tutorial source code I just written.
// this is just an example. do change gui button to back button at your wish. it uses the resultCode to control what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use for nextpage

```
 Intent j = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
    j.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(j);
```

and

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

        finish();
    }
```